# Quando usar o input Button e Submit

Tags: html, html-tags

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de login, mas eu tenho duas alternativas, usar o type button ou type submit, qual delas usar?

```
<div class="layout_login">
    <label for="sizeEmail" id="positionEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="e_mail">
        </br><input class="sizeEmail" type="email" name="e-mail_login">
    </div>
    <label for"sizeSenha" id="positionSenha">Senha</label>
    <div class="senha">
        </br><input class="sizeSenha" type="password" name="senha_login">
    </div>
    <label>Enviar</label>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" << AQUI
    </div>
```

Comment: A diferença é que o tipo **submit** submete as informações em um formulário para um servidor, e o tipo **button** pode ser utilizado como um botão normal como abrir um modal por exemplo.

Comment: O type submit está sendo mais utilizado como botão.